# Threejs and large position values

Tags: three.js

I'm creating an application where I'd like to use real world sizes. Think something in terms of solar system. Currently I'm using OrbitControls and it's seems to break when position gets large although I update the target. Scene starts to wobble see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RhymeBummer/t0fpw41d/1/)

```
camera.position.set(x, y, z - 20);
controls.target.set(x, y, z);
controls.update();
```

Are there any other pitfalls in using large positions?

Comment: I have no idea why that jitters like that. I can't make much sense of your code though.. I'm not sure how it even functions at all. Shrug. Instead, I wrote a new fiddle using similarly very large numbers, and it's smooth as can be http://jsfiddle.net/8m7btpe7/    There is however, problems with pointlights at very large sizes. There was just a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731034/three-js-r75-pointlight-shadows-in-wrong-places  As that answer points out, there's no reason to use very large numbers anyways.

Comment: @Radio so I broke your fiddle, now it jitters like it should :) The thing was in orbitcontrols's target. You left it as (0,0,0) but I'd like to change it dependant on the subject's it's supposed to rotate around. See broken: http://jsfiddle.net/RhymeBummer/558965f5/ PS! When you zoom out at one point the jittering stops so the target must be wrongly configured...

Answer (score 2):

javascript uses floating point arithmetic(and webgl uses only 32 bit floats) - very big and very small numbers will run into "rounding" problems, if you use smaller (*1/100) numbers jitter will stop for you

see similar question [Objects with big speed are flickering/jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33582258/objects-with-big-speed-are-flickering-jumping/33594713#33594713)

if you want great distances, you can look into log based distances http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer