# three.js r75 pointLight shadows in wrong places

Tags: three.js, shadow

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveow/vb2ehtpL/) containing a fixed Sun and Moons and a moving planet Earth which orbits the Sun.

Here is the code for the two Lights (Ambient and Point) and example objects.

```
        var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x444444);//... for lighting the Sun and other MeshBasicMaterial meshes.
        scene.add(light2);

        //... PointLight
        //  http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight
        var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 10, 150000,1);
        light3.castShadow = true;
        light3.shadow.camera.near = 1;
        light3.shadow.camera.far = 5000;
        light3.shadow.camera.fov = 90;
        // light3.shadowCameraVisible = true;
        light3.shadow.bias = 0.001;
        scene.add( light3 );            

        // SPHERES

        var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 40, 32, 16 );
var SunMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
        this.Sun01 = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom.clone(), SunMaterial );
        Sun01.position.set(-500, 0, 220);           
        scene.add( Sun01 );
        //Sun01.castShadow = false;
        //Sun01.receiveShadow = false;

        light3.position.set( Sun01.position.x, Sun01.position.y , Sun01.position.z);

var moonMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xaa00aa } );
        var Moon02 = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom.clone(), moonMaterial );                
        Moon02.scale.set( 0.5,0.5,0.5 );
        Moon02.position.set(-200, 0, 220);
        scene.add( Moon02 );
        Moon02.castShadow = true;
        Moon02.receiveShadow = false;
```

There are two problems.

Firstly distant fixed moons are not illuminated by the PointLight even though they are within range.

Secondly shadows from the distant moons appear on the (Sun-orbitting) Earth even though the Earth is nearer the Sun than those fixed moons.

Note that an inner fixed moon (named Moon02, magenta in color) does get illuminated by the PointLight and it does cast a shadow on the Earth.

Here is the Renderer set-up code:-

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor( 0x000022 );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                //... Enable Shadows
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;//.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        //renderer.shadowMap.type    = THREE.BasicShadowMap;//
                //renderer.shadowMap.type    = THREE.PCFShadowMap
            renderer.shadowMap.type    = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

My Question = What needs to be done to (a) illuminate the outer moons and (b) ensure the shadows of outer moons do not appear on the (inner, nearer-to-Sun) planet Earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you're spacing things out too far.

Calculating shadows from a point light is very expensive. In fact, THREE.js only added functionality for it [a few months ago](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7153). I can't find anything solid in the documentation yet, but it seems likely that there's a hard coded limit on how far out shadows will be calculated from a point light.

The solution is easy: reduce the space between your objects. There's absolutely no reason that objects need to be thousands of units away from each other when a dozen will suffice. I solved both of your problems [just by reducing all distances and scales by a factor of 10.](http://jsfiddle.net/_jered/8gby8jzk/) I also tweaked the intensity of the PointLight because 10 was pretty harsh haha.

```
// color, intensity, falloff radius, falloff amount
// if falloff radius is 0 then there is no falloff
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: "There's absolutely no reason that objects need to be thousands of units away from each other when a dozen will suffice"  but my app is not a piece of art - it is scientific and introducing artifical distance units is undesirable. "reducing all distances and scales by a factor of 10" is a big deal.  I can't see why three.js should have a problem with large distances.  But thanks for the (hopefully temporary) work-around :-).

Comment: @steveOw Well, distances are arbitrary. Even if your app is scientific, you can use whatever units you want behind the scenes in THREE.js because it's trivial to convert between them. If it helps you maintain a mental model of the actual distances then divide by a nice clean number like 1,000 and think in terms of millions of meters instead of millions of kilometers (or whatever).

Comment: Also, normally THREE.js doesn't have a big problem with large distances, I think it's only the PointLight giving you trouble here. Projecting light and shadows in all directions is tough because the projected "rays" spread out as a square of the distance, so they can only go so far. A DirectionalLight by comparison doesn't spread out, its rays are parallel forever, which is much easier to compute. There might be some kind of undocumented "scale factor" that you could tweak instead of changing everything else, but I'm unaware of one.

Comment: Following your thoughts I just found this in [three.js github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8559) - "In the point light shadow map code we apply a scale factor of 1 / 1000...".  It looks like this is the source of my problems.